# XSLT: Leaving out unnecessary text

Tags: xml, xslt, text, output, built-in

Using this built-in template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@*"/>
```

I'm trying to leave out all the text, which will not appear in the output XML elements.

It works for most of the code, but it doesn't work for this part:

```
<xsl:template match="NAD_01">
    <xsl:variable name="a" select="NAD_01_3035"/>
    <xsl:if test="$a='BY'">                                  
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="BY"/>  
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$a='SE'">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="SE"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$a='ST'">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="ST"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="NAD_01_C080" mode="SE">
    <E1EDKA1>
        <PARVW>LF</PARVW>
        <xsl:if test="exists(NAD_01_3036_01)">                      
            <NAME1><xsl:value-of select="NAD_01_3036_01"/></NAME1>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="exists(NAD_01_3036_02)">
            <NAME1><xsl:value-of select="NAD_01_3036_02"/></NAME1>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="exists(NAD_01_3036_03)">
            <NAME1><xsl:value-of select="NAD_01_3036_03"/></NAME1>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="exists(NAD_01_3036_04)">
            <NAME1><xsl:value-of select="NAD_01_3036_04"/></NAME1>
        </xsl:if>
    </E1EDKA1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="NAD_01_C082" mode="BY">              
    <EDIDC>
        <SNDRPRN><xsl:value-of select="NAD_01_3039"/></SNDRPRN>
    </EDIDC>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="NAD_01_C082" mode="SE">         
    <EDIDC>
        <RVNPRN><xsl:value-of select="NAD_01_3039"/></RVNPRN>
    </EDIDC>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="NAD_01_C082" mode="ST">           
    <E1EDKA1>
        <PARVW>WE</PARVW>
        <PARTN><xsl:value-of select="NAD_01_3039"/></PARTN>
    </E1EDKA1>
</xsl:template>
```

Text in the input elements in the section "NAD_01" and in its childs (for example like "NAD_01_3039", but different ones, which don't have any output elements) stays in the output.

I have no idea where is the problem. Maybe with the variable, maybe with the mode links...

Please, how can I leave out all the unnecessary text even in this "NAD_01" section?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what the input XML is.  Is the input an XSL stylesheet?  Please _clearly_ distinguish between the input XML and the XSL that is processing the input.  If the input is some other XML, please provide it as well.

Comment: Input is XML (EDIFACT), output is XML (IDOC). I'm using XSLT version 1.0

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, including the input and the expected output - see: [mcve]. Without it, we can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add that template separately for any of the used modes:

```
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="BY"/>
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="SE"/>
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="ST"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

The template you present,

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@*"/>
```

does not affirmatively suppress text or attribute nodes.  It merely expresses a transformation of such nodes that, *when applied*, produces nothing.  If you're getting unwanted text nodes in your result document then it is because of a rule expressed in some other template that either has higher precedence than that one, or matches different nodes, or operates in a different mode.

A definitive answer cannot be given for your fragments of XSL and altogether unspecified input document, but just in what you've presented I observe that

- You have multiple modes in use, and the transform-to-nothing template you present applies only to the default mode.
- You are using `<xsl:value-of>` elements to create output text nodes from input document elements.  The string value of an element node is a concatenation of the string values of all its text node descendants, which could well include the unwanted text nodes.